# Effects of enabling service broker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I would like to use SqlCacheDependency to update a dataset in real-time, but we have not enabled the service broker on our production database. Could enabling the service broker have any adverse effects (performance, reliability, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely Service Broker is enabled in your production database. It is enabled by default, it only gets disabled on restore in order to prevent distributed split-brains scenarios.

Comment: And what if they actually did disable it? Conversely, is there any advantage to disabling it if it's not being used?

Comment: @JonSeigel: Basically, no, there is no advantage in disabling it. Unless you explicitly want to prevent its usage (for whatever reason) having it enabled and not used is basically 0 cost.